# ASP.Net  using AJAX functionality Jquery or AJAX Toolkit?

Tags: .net, ajax, jquery

i wondering what the best way to achieve the application needs of AJAX requests in the .net environment

I know i can use

```
AJAX toolkit 

or 

Jquery
```

to directly manipulate and send/receive request from the server.

My question is which way is more reliable and most flexible way to achieve this ajax functionality ? I don't want to be using both, it makes a mess.

Answer (score 0):

In my view, you're better off going the jQuery route.

The Microsoft AJAX Toolkit is, in my view, yet another needless abstraction which ties you into a proprietary version of the technology.  Works great when you don't travel off the beaten path, but can cause massive headaches when you run into an issue ( you're not just solving an AJAX problem, you're solving a MS-provided AJAX solution ).

The jQuery route will be more difficult to start with, but you'll end up with a much better understanding of what is going on under the hood, and you can combine those front-end skills with different back-end technologies, unlike with the AJAX Toolkit, which pretty much ties you to .NET.